# Can't use custom maintenance page

Tags: .htaccess

Because I have a dynamic IP address I have used the following lines in my htaccess file to display a custom maintenance page when I need to maintain the site. When not needed I comment out these lines.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*secret-cookie.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* maintenance-page.html [NC,L,R=503]
```

With the secret-cookie installed on Firefox using Firecookie, I can see the Website on Firefox while I'm working on it and if I view the site on IE I see the maintenance page because IE doesn't have the cookie. The cookie part of the system works correctly.
The problem is that my custom maintenance-page is not shown. Instead the standard "`Service Temporarily Unavailable`" page is shown. I've tried a few permutations of the RewriteRule line but always the standard page is shown instead of my custom page.

Comment: Is it the server's "temporarily unavailable" page or the browser's?

Comment: I believe it's the server's page because it states on the page Apache Server at www.mysite.com Port ***